# Ojdbc7 doesn't contain oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes.CURSOR

Tags: java, jdbc, ojdbc

Currently we are using (`oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes.CURSOR`) with `registerOutParameter` using  ojdb14

Now we are migrating ojdbc7. What is new mode as 
oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes is even not visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Oracle JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleTypes.html) this is `oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR`

The class is defined public, so it is accessible.

The following code compiles fine:

```
public class OracleTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("CURSOR is: " + oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
  }
}
```

And prints:

```
CURSOR is: -10
```

Comment: I might be worthwhile to explicitly say this class was moved to a different package (old: `oracle.jdbc.driver` vs new: `oracle.jdbc`)

Comment: Thank you very much for answers and explanation

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: it wasn't really moved. `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes` was never officially "supported". Only `oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR` was part of the official JavaDocs, See e.g. here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/datacc.htm#g1028145

Comment: I think it was moved, somewhere between version 9 and 10 of the driver (I think they also moved the driver-class from `oracle.jdbc.driver` to `oracle.jdbc` around that time), but I don't want to go on an archaeological expedition to confirm that.